# While doing Ajax call i am unable to post <script>alert('123');</script>. I have used encodeURI, encodeURIComponent and escape. Still not working

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var data = encodeURI("<script>alert('123');</script>");
alert(data);
```

// *Unable to get the alert('123'); in alert due to **>**         symbol*

// *button click even helps in posting data on backend*

```
 $("button").click(function(){
            $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
            {
              name: data ,
              city: "Duckburg"
            },
            function(data,status){
                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            });
        });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your sequence is not correctly escaped.

try

```
var data = encodeURI("<script>alert('123');<\/script>");
```

instead of

```
var data = encodeURI("<script>alert('123');</script>");
```

Comment: @AlfaDhavalThakkar you are welcome. Please vote the answer up and mark it as an answer :)